# REGEX: what is the index of capturing group when using with vertical bar

Tags: regex, regex-group

My regular expression is like `(a=)true|(b=)true` (this is the simple version, the real one is more complicated)

Assume the text is

```
a=true
b=true
```

Then I know either `a=` or `b=` is always `\1` (or `$1`)

But what if the text is like

```
a=true b=true
```

I find the `a=` is `\1`, `b=` is `\2`.

**As @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi said, the statement below is not true. I struck them out**

<s>If the text is</s>

```
b=true a=true
```

Then `b=` is `\1`, `a=` is `\2`.

It brings me trouble if the index is not stable, depends on the order of occurrence.

How to explain this result? It would be great if anyone can redirect me to the official document. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

- If pattern is only `(a=)true`, `(a=)` will always be `\1`.
- If pattern is only `(b=)true`, `(b=)` will always be `\1`.
- (In my opinion) the patterns on both sides of the vertical bar (pipe symbol) are parallel.

Based on the 3 statements above, I expect in pattern `(a=)true|(b=)true`, either `(a=)` or `(b=)` will still be `\1`. So that I could use one index to refer to both of them, like substitution, `s/(a=)true|(b=)true/\1false/g`. But the fact is not what I expect.

If change the pattern to `(a=|b=)true`, then I can always use `\1` to refer to them.

So my question is, can I use only one index to refer to the capturing group in pattern `(a=)true|(b=)true`? or I have to change the pattern to `(a=|b=)true`?

Comment: You can maybe use named groups, but I'm not sure if your language supports it. Which language and regex flavor you're using?

Comment: Your assumption is a little incorrect here. In your regex `(a=)true|(b=)true` `\1` is always `a=` and `\2` is always `b=` no matter the order. What language/tool are you using? And can you brief what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Boy: Why don't you see which group id it is? As long as the regex actually contains two groups, both the groups are accessible, and the one that matches will print the value and the other will print null. Try it out and see. At least this is how it is in Java and in most other languages/tools.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You are right, thank you for correcting me. It indeed does return empty group for such case.

Comment: @Boy: You're welcome brother.

Comment: Capturing group index only depends on the group position inside the pattern. So, the issue described cannot occur: `(a=)` is always Group 1 and `(b=)` is always Group 2.

Comment: You guys are right. I just updated my question. Thank you for pointing out my error.